# Merging/Injecting Partial Code with Git

Tags: git, version-control

Okay I do not believe this has been asked, although similar things have. Still I will do my best to convey the entire concept with as much clarity as I can.

I have a primary program in GIT that gets updated by another team and I have no control over how they update that program.  I will call this program Source.pgm

Now I have a series of changes that I implement to Source.pgm that would like to put into their own repository.  These changes cannot be "run" as they are only transformation changes thus not a fully functional program.  Thus these changes are not contained in a specific directory or module and they simply alter Source.pgm to morph it into Utlimate.pgm.  As sort of stated, these changes are scattered throughout the source code of Source.pgm but I want to create a single and separate repository that holds just these changes (and any future changes) so that when changes occur to Source.pgm all I need to do is "merge"/"inject" the pieces that change Source.pgm and make it Ultimate.pgm (in places complete overwrite, other places modify lines of code, and in even other places add in new items) --  I would of course check what changes occurred to Source.pgm prior to running this "merge" so that I am sure that their changes do not affect anything related to Ultimate.pgm and if they did adjust the transform code snippets for Ultimate.pgm to make accommodations for these changes.  However most of the time the changes do not effect Ultimate.pgm and a straight "merge"/"injection" is just fine

Now would I do this with Submodules?  I was reading up on that but I am not sure if that would allow me to do this as they seem to talk about completely autonomous packages (projects such as a library, modules, etc..) to be made into a submodule where my changes, as I stated, change/modify some lines of code in some files, completely overwrite (replace) several other files, as well as add several brand new files into numerous places throughout the source code for Source.pgm that then transforms it into Ultimate.pgm.

If Submodules are not the way to go is there another feature of GIT that would allow me to do this.  I know I could write a script that would "inject" my changes into the source code of Source.pgm but I was hoping that I could do it all with something within GIT.

Thanks in advance